How can I restore the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder?
I'm new to Linux and did something stupid. I'm using Kali and after apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, I encountered some issues. The desktop items were missing and windows no longer had a "bar", along with some other things. While trying to fix that, I messed it up way more..
I found that it was caused by a libGL error where it failed to load the swrast driver.
Someone on this site suggested renaming /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.bak which I did with the mv command.
It was stupid to do so without thinking about what that could impact. Now I can no longer run most commands (I will get an error: command_not_found_handler:2: /usr/lib/command-not-found: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory) I'm trying to move the folder back with mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.bak /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu but it results in the same error. So does using BusyBox.
I've tried using ../sbin/sln x_86-64-linux-gnu.bak x_86-64-linux-gnu but it says there is no such file or directory.
Any ideas on what I can try or have I already lost all my data?

"Someone on this site" - is that part of a question or answer? If so can you link to it please so it can be checked for accuracy

"I'm new to Linux and did something stupid. I'm using Kali" - Please DO NOT use Kali if you are new to Linux. Use a more friendly distribution while you get used to the environment, and then considering maybe possibly perhaps moving to Kali if you have a security/pentest role. Certainly, don't use Kali as your daily driver

What data do you need to recover? You could boot a live Linux system, e.g from an Ubuntu installation media, mount your harddisk and backup the important data. You could also rename the directory to the original name from this live system. Please [edit] your question to add information.
